# How to parallel a for loop in shell using GNU parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have an executable file, when we execute that ask for input (filename) manually. The code is perfectly running in a bash script, however when I try using GNU parallel it not taking the input automatically: (Note: I have thousands of *.DS0 files). Here when it executes the executable file pops up message for the input file name, which is given using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for entry in *.DS0;do
   echo "$entry" | ./executbale  
done
```

Please help to write the same code using GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
parallel 'echo {} | ./executable'  ::: *.DS0
```